# Oracle Apex - Limit only one checkbox be checked in all rows of Interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a checkbox column and this checkbox can be checked only in 1 row no matter how many rows there are in IG.

I've tried using JS by looping through all records and de-checking checkboxes that are not selected, but I have a problem here because the dynamic action click on the column does not trigger.

Only one checkbox can be checked. I would expect the other checkbox to be deselected.

I am using Oracle APEX 21.2.8

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what behaviour you are expecting ? For example if I checked row 1 and then checked row 2 - what do you expect to happen ? Does the user get a message ? Does the checkbox on row 1 get unchecked ? Are you talking about the behaviour in the IG before it is saved or a validation ? Please update your question with as much info as possible

Comment: Only one checkbox can be checked. I would expect the other checkbox to be deselected.

Comment: Not sure I'll be able to help, maybe others can. Can you update your question with what you have so far ? Also, don't put clarification (like your last comment) in the comments but update your question.

Comment: In HTML, you would normally use a radio button rather than a checkbox if you only want one thing to be selected.

Comment: @MT0, Joze has an IG. How would you apply a radio button functionality to it & problem he described?

Comment: @MTO - The OP wants only 1 checkbox across multiple Interactive Grid rows. Radio buttons are only good for choosing a single value in a single field, not across multiple rows.

Comment: Have you solved this question? I am attempting to do something similar and would appreciate your follow up.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one checkbox column on each row that you need to be unique across all rows, I would think you could use the **Selection Change - Interactive Grid** event to invoke your Javascript.